# How do i disable page transition animations in windows phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, transition

I'm using the windows phone toolkit for page transitions, and i binded the pagetransition animation in the app.xaml, my question is how do i disable a transition from page 1 to page 2, but i don't want to remove all transitions from page 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try setting the `TransitionService.NavigationInTransition` to null.

reference:

[stop wp7 out transitions while canceling navigation on OnNavigatingFrom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564334/)